# Batch conversion of Sounds with Different Format to one Format, how?

Tags: conversion

Discussion in Freesound.org, [here](http://www.freesound.org/forum/freesound-project/32415/), is stagnated. You could do this with Audacity but their developer warned about that (apparently stupid idea to load the GUIs or something like that). Is there something like ImageMagick for sounds? I have a repository full of small music pieces (UX sounds etc) that I need to one consistent format, how can I do that?

Comment: I would search the web for a sound converter for your system. Whether you're on Linux, Windows or OS X, you'll probably going to find something.

Answer (score 6):

The following example will make a directory called `outputdir` and then re-encode all wav inputs in the current directory to mp3:

```
mkdir outputdir
for f in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 outputdir/"${f%.wav}.mp3"; done
```

You can use a slightly modified command to convert multiple formats to MP3:

```
mkdir outputdir
for f in *.{wav,aiff,flac,m4a}; do ffmpeg -i "$f" \
-c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 outputdir/"${f%.*}.mp3"
```

Use whatever file extensions you want in there, but remember that converting one from one lossy codec to another is a bad idea (so converting ogg vorbis to mp3 wouldn't work well).

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, ffmpeg + [Avanti](http://avanti.arrozcru.com/) will do the trick. Just perform the conversion on a single audio file, then queue all the rest in the job manager and go.

Comment: ...well not using W but *ix systems but perhaps useful for others.